# How to add Models in Camera View in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, artificial-intelligence, augmented-reality, image-recognition

I'm developing Augmented Reality base Application in android.
In which I want to add model or image when camera view open.

How can I do that with Android Studio?

I know there are libraries like vuforia but I don't want to use library.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want image recognition or just to place an image in an AR scene?

[ARCore](https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/getting-started) by Google supports augmented reality and allows you to orient the device in the world, but does not yet support image recognition, so no detecting an image. To do image recognition, you'll need to use an external library/service (like Vuforia which you mentioned above).

If you want to use iOS, ARKit 1.5 (coming out in iOS 11.3) will support [Image Detection](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/recognizing_images_in_an_ar_experience).

If you want to build cross platform, check out my company's product [Viro React](https://viromedia.com/viroreact) which enables you to build a cross-platform AR/VR application. We'll support both ARKit and ARCore features as they come out. It's free and easy to use!

Comment: Yes i want image recognition too. By the way thank you.

Comment: Hi @AhsanAzwar, in that case you'll have to use some 3rd party library like Vuforia, or swing your own solution using OpenCV or ARToolKit. Although, with ARKit introducing Image Detection (they don't handle tracking too well), we expect that Google should come out with a similar API within the next 3 months for ARCore.